# Huge time gap between spark jobs

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark, time, pivot

I create and persist a df1 on which then I am doing the below:

```
df1.persist (From the Storage Tab in spark UI it says it is 3Gb)

df2=df1.groupby(col1).pivot(col2) (This is a df with 4.827 columns and 40107 rows)
df2.collect
df3=df1.groupby(col2).pivot(col1) (This is a df with 40.107 columns and 4.827 rows)

-----it hangs here for almost 2 hours-----

df4 = (..Imputer or na.fill on df3..)
df5 = (..VectorAssembler on df4..)
(..PCA on df5..)
df1.unpersist
```

I have a cluster with 16 nodes(each node has 1 worker with 1 executor with 4 cores and 24Gb Ram) and a master(with 15Gb of Ram). Also spark.shuffle.partitions is 192. It hangs for 2 hours and nothing is happening. Nothing is active in Spark UI. Why does it hang for so long? Is it the DagScheduler? How can I check it? Please let me know if you need any more information.

**----Edited 1----**

After waiting for almost two hours it proceeds and then eventually fails. Below is the stages and executor tabs from Spark UI:
[image: Stages]
[image: Executors]

Also, in the stderr file in the worker nodes it says:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000003fe900000, 6434586624, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
```

Moreover, it seems there is a file produced named "hs_err_pid11877" in the folder next to stderr and stdout which says:

> There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
> Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 6434586624 bytes for committing reserved memory.
> Possible reasons:
> The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
> The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native heap
> Possible solutions:
> Reduce memory load on the system
> Increase physical memory or swap space
> Check if swap backing store is full
> Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
> Decrease number of Java threads
> Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
> Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
> JVM is running with Zero Based Compressed Oops mode in which the Java heap is
> placed in the first 32GB address space. The Java Heap base address is the
> maximum limit for the native heap growth. Please use -XX:HeapBaseMinAddress
> to set the Java Heap base and to place the Java Heap above 32GB virtual address.
> This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
> Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2792), pid=11877, tid=0x00007f237c1f8700
> JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_265-b01) (build 1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~18.04-b01)
> Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.265-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
> Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

...and other information about the task it fails, GC information, etc..

**----Edited 2----**

Here is the Tasks Section of the the last pivot(stage with id 16 from stages picture).. just before the hanging. It seems that all 192 partitions have a pretty equal amount of data, from 15 to 20MB.

[image: tasksSection]

Comment: can you update your question with Task details in Spark UI? maybe data is skewed! take a small subsample from data and work on it

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, although I do not think data is skewed. I will upload the stages tab and executor tab. It works completely fine with e.g. 5.000 columns (although it still hangs for 10 minutes in the same spot).

Comment: I am wildly suspect that the one of the groupby causes a few big partitions and a lot of small partitions hence a few executors do the heavy lifting, Task details may be useful, with Task details I mean "Tasks section" of this https://mallikarjuna_g.gitbooks.io/spark/content/spark-webui-StagePage.html

Comment: The hanging usually happens, when spark is doing some meta data work. Example : when i try to read 90000 files, it hangs for 15 minutes.  In your case also, It's trying to create some meta data for the upcoming Dataframe. ( 4000 columns : 10 mins, 40000 columns : 100 mins).  The hanging has nothing to do with your error. But yes, it's undesirable.

Comment: Both of your error's are JVM errors, there should be another Spark output error whose stack trace can give better debugging info.  But yes, it looks like an `oom` issue. Which version of spark are you using? are you using any memory config ? @Des0lat0r

Comment: Yes maybe the hanging makes a bit sense now. Is there any way I can avoid all 1.5hrs of hanging or is it necessary metadata? I am using 2.4.3 version and the only memory config I am doing is .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "8g"), .config("spark.executor.memory","24g") and the 15g for the driver when I start my application with "Java -jar -Xmx15g app.jar".

Comment: pivot initiates a Stage as well

Comment: So it seems the hanging time cannot be avoided! However, after all these I get an error "MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing location for output shuffle 6". Can this be now somehow related? In order to solve it I am currently playing with the memory configuration, numbero of executors and cores..! I guess I should post an other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pivot` in Spark generates an extra Stage to get the pivot values, that happens underwater and can take some time and depends how your resources are allocated, etc.

Comment: I there any way to reduce this time? For example assigning cores to the driver(if possible)? I have 16 executors(4 cores each with 20g of memory) and a master with 15g of memory. Shuffle partitions is 192.

Comment: No the driver has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Check. Try increasing aspects on driver as under the hood a collect is most likely occurring. Getting all the values for the cols.

Comment: Played a bit with driver memory and partitions, or try to collect data to driver but still hangs..! I do not mind that a lot. Mostly I care for the error of Missing output location for shuffle that comes during pca at stage treeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:122. But that is a different post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64551151/spark-java-pca-java-heap-space-and-missing-output-location-for-shuffle